# How to put my javascript map into php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have javascript for a google map and need to put php variables in where the longitude and latitude values are, but I am unsure on how to do allow javascript to work inside a php file, how do I do this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: **-34.397**, lng: **150.644**},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

What I need is to change the "lat: " and "long: " to have two php variables in it, for example:

```
lat: $myVariableLat;
lng: $myVariableLng;
```

And have the javascript above working inside my php file

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there's a webserver in your setup running a .php file(s) that is displaying a webpage.

You need to understand that the .php file is just rendering the result of it's contents. This means you need to embed the variable you care about into the html /javascript you're wanting displayed.

If the above is valid, the contents of your .php file would look something like this.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: <?php   echo $myVariableLat; ?>, lng: <?php   echo $myVariableLng; ?>},
  zoom: 8
 });
}
 </script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs client-side, PHP gets executed before the document/data is even sent.

If your longitude and latitude don't need to dynamically change then you can use this php code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: <?=$myVariableLat?>, lng: <?=$myVariableLng?>},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

PHP will run and insert the values in your JavaScript.

`<?=` opens a new php tag and echos the following value. `?>` just closes the php tag

The result should look like this:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```